# Increasing the font size of described term in a description list

Tags: fontsize, enumitem, description

I have a description list defined like this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{description}[style=nextline]
\item[Design Patterns]
Descriptive Text.
\item[Code Quality]
Descriptive Text.
\item[Programming Paradigms]
Descriptive Text.
\end{description}
```

This displays the descriptive text in the same font size as the described term.

How do i increase the font size of the described term, while keeping the descriptive text at the document specified size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How much bigger should the header items (the "described terms") be?

Comment: I would like to specify them in a relative way, preferably `1.5em`.

Comment: I have no prior experience with LaTeX, so i assumed that `em` works similar to HTML/CSS. I will stick with the aforementioned commands then. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've loaded the `enumitem` package, you could simply specify the setup option `font=\large` (or `font=\huge`, or whatever) in addition to `style=nextline`.

To obtain an *absolute* font size for the "described terms" of, say, `1.5em`, use the instruction

```
\begin{description}[style=nextline,font={\fontsize{1.5em}{1.8em}\selectfont}]
```

This sets the baselineskip to 120% of the font size. If you want either more or less leading, simply replace `1.8em` with your preferred length value.

A compilable MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline,font=\large]
\item[Design Patterns]
Descriptive Text.
\item[Code Quality]
Descriptive Text.
\item[Programming Paradigms]
Descriptive Text.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```